# Excel - efficient way to find data across sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I currently have a spreadsheet with two work sheets. The first worksheet is a list of names and addresses, the second is a list with names and addresses plus email addresses (sheet is named "EmailList")

I am trying to add a new column to the first worksheet that will show the email address if the email is in the second sheet by matching the firstname, lastname, house number and street address. Even better would be to show the list on a new sheet with just whole rows that match.

I got the email showing using:

```
=INDEX(EmailList!P:P, MATCH(A9&B9&C9&E9, EmailList!A:A&EmailList!B:B&EmailList!C:C&EmailList!E:E, 0))
```

However it is soooooo slow. The first sheet has a 1000 rows, the second sheet 1500.

How can I easily select the rows from the EmailList sheet where the Firstname, Lastname, Number, Street name columns in both sheets match?

Comment: Consider an SQL solution if you use Excel for PC. In fact, your last sentence literally wrote your SQL statement with words *Select* and *Where* with list of columns!

Comment: Limit the searched ranges just to the rows that have data. For example `EmailList!P1:P1000`

Comment: or .. you can create a PivotTable with both ranges https://www.google.com/search?q=pivot+table+multiple+ranges&tbm=vid

Answer (score 0):

The comments by pnuts and Parfait are both excellent suggestions and worth considering.

I'm just wondering if your structural logic is correct. From what you write in your questions, rather than find email address for Sheet1, aren't you actually removing from Sheet2 any addresses that don't exist on Sheet1? If this is the case, then a VBA solution would be quite short and simple. If you created a string key from your names, house number, address cells, you could populate a `Collection` and simply look up that key in each Sheet2 entry. Some skeleton code for you to develop would be as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunMe()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
    Dim key As String
    Dim addrs As Collection
    Dim emails As Collection
    Dim hit As Boolean
    Dim vRow As Variant
    Dim output As Variant

    'Read addresses from Sheet1 into collection
    data = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value2
    Set addrs = New Collection
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        key = BuildKey(data, r)
        addrs.Add True, key
    Next

    'Interrogate email list
    data = Sheet2.UsedRange.Value2
    Set emails = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        key = BuildKey(data, r)
        hit = False
        hit = addrs(key)
        If hit Then emails.Add r
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Write your results to the new sheet
    ReDim output(1 To emails.Count, 1 To 5)
    i = 1
    For Each vRow In emails
        For c = 1 To 5
            output(i, c) = data(vRow, c)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Sheet3.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output

End Sub
Private Function BuildKey(data As Variant, r As Long) As String
    Dim c As Long

    For c = 1 To 4
        BuildKey = BuildKey & CStr(data(r, c)) & "|"
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, consider SQL if using Excel for PC. Excel can connect to the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Window .dll files) to run queries on worksheets as if they were database tables. And yes, you can query the very workbook you run the macro as you will use a read-only instance of last saved file.

Specifically, the query below runs an `INNER JOIN` between two sheets, *MainList* and *EmailList* on the very columns you specified with output to existing worksheet, *Results*:

```
Sub RunSQL()    
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRINGS (DRIVER VERSION COMMENTED OUT)
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    strSQL = " SELECT t1.*, t2.[EmailAddress]" _
                & " FROM [MainList$] t1" _
                & " INNER JOIN [EmailList$] t2" _
                & " ON t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName" _
                & " AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName" _
                & " AND t1.HouseNumber = t2.HouseNumber" _
                & " AND t1.StreeAddress = t2.StreetAddress;"            
    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Results").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i).Name
    Next i        
    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close: conn.Close    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dev site, but if you want a super-easy to do this with no code whatsoever, you can use PowerPivot, which is a free AddIn.

[image]

[image]

You can get the AddIn from here.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Power-Pivot-Add-in-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045

Again, it's just another option for you.  I like Parfait's suggestion!  Very elegant, sir!!